# What's the loop space of a circle?

Tags: algebraic-topology, loop-spaces

Is it true that the loop space of a circle is contractible? Consider the long exact sequence in homotopy for the path fibration $\Omega S^1 \rightarrow \ast \rightarrow S^1$ shows all homotopy groups of the loop space to be zero, and then Whitehead's theorem kicks in and tells us that $\Omega S^1$ is contractible.

I can't see any flaw in this argument, but it's really rankling against my intuition of what a loop space "is". For instance, we know that $S^1$ has $\mathbb{Z}$ many loops *up to homotopy*, so surely it should have a fairly complicated loop space? So I suppose that there are two possible approaches to answering this question: either point out where I'm going wrong in my mathematics, or help rectify my intuition.

Secondly, does this generalise to the $n$-fold loop space of an $n$-sphere? I think it does; I've used the Serre spectral sequence to compute the cohomology rings of loop spaces of spheres and they all die at $\Omega^n S^n$.

Sorry for the "please check my working" nature of the question; it's sufficiently early in my mathematical life that I'm never convinced that there's no errors in my working (especially not with spectral sequences, which still feel a bit like doing magic to me). It was a lot easier to be (mathematically) confident as an undergraduate, when you could check your working against solutions sheets...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

$\Omega S^1\cong \mathbb Z$ — your argument is almost correct: each connected component is contractible, but there are countably many such components ($\pi_0(\Omega S^1)=\pi_1(S^1)=\mathbb Z$).

As for $\Omega^n S^n$, these spaces have very non-trivial homotopy type: $\pi_k(\Omega^n S^n)=\pi_{n+k}S^n$ and there are a lot of non-trivial homotopy groups of spheres (say, $\pi_1(\Omega^2 S^2)=\pi_3(S^2)=\mathbb Z$, $\pi_1(\Omega^3 S^3)=\pi_4(S^3)=\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ etc).

---

As for the Serre spectral sequence, maybe you made the standard mistake: when computing, say, $H(\Omega S^3)$ one sees that there is an element $x$ s.t. $d_2(x)=[S^3]$ and concludes that (since powers of $x$ "obviously" kill all cohomology classes from $E_2$) $H(\Omega S^3)$ "is" $\mathbb Z[x]$. But actually $d_2(x^n)=\mathbf{n}x[S^3]$, so powers of $x$ don't kill all classes: there also should exist classes $x^n/n!$ and the answer is not $\mathbb Z[X]$ but $\Gamma[x]$.

Comment: Yes, I see now: the homotopy groups see it as zero, since the space is discrete, but we can use the isomorphism $\pi_n(X) \cong \pi_{n-1}(X)$ to spot that it has $\Z$ many such connected components. Cheers. Can we say anything about the cohomology of the spaces $\Omega^n S^n$? I have their $n$th cohomology groups dying, but my working is probably very shaky.

Comment: I have that the loop space is the divided polynomial algebra (or the divided polynomial algebra tensor an exterior algebra for even spheres), and then I considered the fibration $\Omega^2 X \rightarrow \ast \rightarrow \Omega X$ (where $X$ is a sphere). This has a Serre spectral sequence with blank stable page and $E_2$ page consisting of columns only in multiples of $n-1$. Everything on the $E_2$ page has to disappear, so the first $n-1$ $d_{n-1}$ differentials in the first column have to be isomorphims, so as to kill $E^{n-1, 0}, \ldots, E^{n-1, n-1}$, whose "outward" differentials all map

Comment: to zero. And continuing through the sequence like this, we get isomorphims $H^i \Omega^2 S^n \cong H^{i - n + 2} \Omega^2 S^n$, which give us that the cohomology of $\Omega^2 S^n$ is $\mathbb{Z}$ in dim $0, n-2, 2n-2, \ldots $ and zero elsewhere. We can then move onto the next path fibration in the sequence, where it'll be the $n-2$ differentials we need to look at and the cohomology will be nontrivial at multiples of $n-3$, and so on. That's my working in computing the cohomology *modules* of $\Omega^j S^n$, at any rate. With my working, when $j=n$, the cohomology must be zero.

Comment: And then from there we can compute the ring structure... but I figure it's best to sort out my mistakes one step at a time. Also, comments are terrible for trying to do actual maths in.

Comment: @Alex I haven't checked your argument, but clearly $H_1(\Omega^2S^2)=\pi_1(\Omega^2S^2)=\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\neq0$...

Comment: @Alex ...and in general the question about cohomology of $\Omega^n S^n$ is not easy, AFAIK. One should, perhaps, start from classical paper http://www.jstor.org/pss/2372804 of Dyer and Lashof

Comment: @Grigory, hah, I just scribbled that in my notebook after typing that out. Clearly something's gone wrong here in my understanding of spectral sequences; I think I have to put effort into the $2n-2$, $3n-3$, etc columns; these could mean some maps I assumed were isomorphisms are just monic/epic, for instance. Drawing board, back to it. Thanks for your time, btw! (And thanks for the paper. :) )

Comment: Yes, (if you're interested) you should ask a separate question about $H(\Omega^n S^n)$, perhaps

Comment: (For what it's worth, the problems with my spectral sequence argument are those of connectivity; $\Omega S^2$ is not simply-connected, and so I'm using a spectral sequence that does not exist. These are the perils of performing mathematics before a) coffee; and b) engaging one's brain.)

Comment: After many years clearly, however I have to ask. Hope someone is here to give an answer. Probably I misunderstand something, but why $\pi_3(\mathbf{S}^2) \cong \mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$? Isn't isomorphic with $\pi_3(\mathbf{S}^3) \cong \mathbf{Z}$, from Hopf fibration?

Comment: @mayer_vietoris Indeed, thank you.